# Excel: Calculate the number of loan payments between two dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have problem I need help with. I have two dates for loan: current date and the maturity date. I also have information about which day of the month/quarter/year payment will be transfered. So the question is: How do I calculate the number of payments between the two dates when loans have different payment schedules. So for example:

Current date: 2.12.2020
Maturity: 15.6.2021
Payment day: 20th
Payments in year: 12

So the result would be: 6 (December, January, February, March, April, May)

Example 2:

Current date: 2.12.2020
Maturity: 15.6.2021
Payment day: 20th
Payments in year: 4 (so quarterly)

Result: 2 (January, April)

Should I use some kind of VBA for loop or what?

Comment: Well which do you want?  Something that calculates the number of times the day of the month happens between two dates like your title states or something that can also account for quarterly and yearly payments?  As is this is a very broad request and not a specific question.

Comment: I now edited the question to be more clear. But yes something that can also account for quarterly and yearly payments. Not necessarily looking for exact solution but information if this could be done with excel's formulas or do I need VBA?

Comment: How do we know that the quarterly starts in Jan and not Feb or March?

Comment: Quarterly and Yearly payments will be done always in the first month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((DAY(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B1)))=C1)*(MOD(MONTH(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,A1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,B1)))-1,12/D1)=0))
```

It iterates the days and tests whether it meets the requirements and adds up where they match.

[image]

If one has Office 365 then we can shorten it with LET and SQUENCE:

```
=LET(dts,SEQUENCE(B1-A1+1,,A1),SUMPRODUCT((DAY(dts)=C1)*(MOD(MONTH(dts)-1,12/D1)=0)))
```

or:

```
=LET(dts,SEQUENCE(,B1-A1+1,A1),COUNT(FILTER(dts,(DAY(dts)=C1)*(MOD(MONTH(dts)-1,12/D1)=0))))
```

Comment: Thanks man, saved my night!